# Css fit children elements to parent height

Tags: css

I want to create a profile-like page. The contents would be like:

```
<profile_entry_name> |<textfield_to_edit_entry>|
```

So I have something like this:

```
<div className="row">
  <p>First name</p>
  <TextField variant="outlined" />
</div>
```

To make everything appear on the same line I did:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 20px;
}
```

The `height: 20px;` is key here. It doesn't have to be `20px`, I put this value to check if it works properly. The problem is:

- even the paragraph doesn't respect its parent `height` param - it appears below
- the textfield behaves the same way

It looks like this:

[image]

Can I somehow change this behavior? I want those to be of equal height (specified by the parent), because I will have many rows like this and I want them to look nice.

P.S `TextField` is a MUI component, but it doesn't really matter I guess, I can style it as well, maybe just by using `!important` on some css props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 20px;
}

.row textarea {
  max-height: 100%
}
```

Comment: Okay, so now they are aligned properly, but still, the textfield is to big and by the way, the paragraph also. It looked good since the paragraph's font size is `16px` and my `row` height is `20px` but when I change it to like `5` or `10px`, this happens: https://imgur.com/a/7of0M4m

Comment: I've even swapped the `TextField` with simple `input` to check, because sometimes MUI components don't interact well with CSS (they don't respect it, or have nested children). This is how it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/Dsr0yzr

Comment: remove margin and padding. And another thing is that you can't make it 10px high if your text font-size is 16px

Comment: I know, 5px or 10px is too small obviously, but this is about how it works. Remove margin and padding -  you mean on the whole row or its elements?

Comment: It is better if you remove margin and padding from `parent` element and from the `children` elements as well

Comment: Okay, it worked even without removing the margins, my browser somehow cached the font sizes from before I changed them. So this is good. Now the only thing that remains is to figure out how to make MUI's `TextField` smaller, but this was not the question, so I am accepting your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```css
 .row {
   display: flex;
 }
```

Default `align-items` value is `stretch` so you don't need to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

Use align-items

```
`align-items: center;`
```

[image]